# Change the size of my component dynamically based on the amount of text in my label

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a simple component, a label and an imageview.
They are put in horizontal position. I need to center that and if my label gets more text, the component will change too and the position of my image will change. I have to do this programmatically and I’m really new to programmatically constraints.

For more explanation this is an example:

[image]

And this is my code right now:

```
class PVProgressIndicator: UIView {
    
    let progressText: UILabel = {
        let progressText = UILabel()
        progressText.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        progressText.text = ""
        progressText.numberOfLines = 0
        progressText.textAlignment = .right
        progressText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressText.sizeToFit()
        progressText.layoutIfNeeded()
        return progressText
    }()
    
    let iconView: UIImageView = {
        let iconView = UIImageView()
        iconView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let image = UIImage(named: "feedback_success")!
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
        let resizedImage = renderer.image { _ in
            image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)))
        }
        iconView.image = resizedImage
        iconView.sizeToFit()
        iconView.layoutIfNeeded()
        return iconView
    }()

       let iconView2: UIImageView = {
        let iconView2 = UIImageView()
        iconView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let image = UIImage(named: "feedback_error")!
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
        let resizedImage = renderer.image { _ in
            image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)))
        }
        iconView2.image = resizedImage
        iconView2.sizeToFit()
        iconView2.layoutIfNeeded()
        return iconView2
    }()
        
    private func setupView() {
        
        let overlayView = UIView()
        overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(overlayView)
        
        overlayView.addSubview(iconView)
        overlayView.addSubview(iconView2)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            iconView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView2.centerXAnchor),
            iconView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView.centerYAnchor),
            progressIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView2.centerXAnchor),
            progressIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView2.centerYAnchor),
            
            iconView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            iconView2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10),
            iconView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10), 
            iconView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])
        
        addSubview(progressText)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            progressText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlayView.trailingAnchor, constant: 15),
            progressText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlayView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Also, this is how I set this in a parent view:

```
private func setupProgressBar() {
    self.codeValidationTextField.addSubview(progressBar)
    
    progressBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    progressBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codeValidationTextField.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    progressBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codeValidationTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: -33).isActive = true
    progressBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codeValidationTextField.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
    progressBar.progressIndicator.isHidden = false
    progressBar.iconView.isHidden = true
    progressBar.progressText.isHidden = false 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do...

- your code references a `progressIndicator` when setting constraints, but there is no `progressIndicator` identified.
- there is no reason to be "scaling" your images... the image view will do that for you.
- you're adding 2 "icon" image views, but the layout doesn't make much sense.
- there is no need to use a `overlayView` -- we can add the subviews to the custom view itself (and, the code you've shown doesn't setup that overlayView correctly, so no idea if it is supposed to be doing anything).

Note that it helps to include comments in your code, telling yourself what you ***expect*** to happen.

And, a tip: during development, give your UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easy to see the framing.

So, let's simplify this and start with a single image view and label:

```
class PVProgressIndicator: UIView {
    
    let progressText: UILabel = {
        let progressText = UILabel()
        progressText.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        progressText.text = ""
        progressText.numberOfLines = 0
        progressText.textAlignment = .right
        progressText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // no need for any of this
        //progressText.sizeToFit()
        //progressText.layoutIfNeeded()
        return progressText
    }()
    
    let iconView: UIImageView = {
        let iconView = UIImageView()
        iconView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let image = UIImage(named: "feedback_success") {
            iconView.image = image
        } else {
            // could not load image, so set background color
            iconView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        }
        // no need for any of this
        //let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
        //let resizedImage = renderer.image { _ in
        //  image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)))
        //}
        //iconView.image = resizedImage
        //iconView.sizeToFit()
        //iconView.layoutIfNeeded()
        return iconView
    }()
    
    private func setupView() {
        
        // no need for this... add subviews to self
        //let overlayView = UIView()
        //overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //addSubview(overlayView)
        
        self.addSubview(iconView)
        self.addSubview(progressText)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // 20-points on top and bottom of iconView
            iconView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            iconView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // align iconView to leading-edge of self
            iconView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // iconView 16 x 16
            iconView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
            iconView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
            
            // progressText centered vertically
            progressText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            
            // progressText 15-points from iconView trailing edge
            progressText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView.trailingAnchor, constant: 15.0),

            // align progressText to trailing-edge of self
            progressText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])

        // during development, use some background colors so we can see the framing
        progressText.backgroundColor = .cyan
        self.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupView()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupView()
    }
}
```

And an example view controller showing it. Each tap anywhere in the view will cycle through several "example" progress strings:

```
class PVTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let progressBar = PVProgressIndicator()
    
    let sampleStrings: [String] = [
        "Short",
        "Medium Length",
        "A Longer Sample String",
        "This one should be long enough that it will word wrap onto more than one line.",
        "Let's make this sample string\nuse\n4 lines\nof text.",
        "If the progress text might be very, very long... so long that it could wrap onto more than four lines (like this), then some additional constraints will need to be set on the elements in the progressBar view.",
    ]
    var sampleIDX: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        progressBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(progressBar)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain progressBar Top 20-points from top of safe area
            progressBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            // centered horizontally
            progressBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            // let's set the max width to 75% of safe area width
            progressBar.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            
            // progressBar sets it's own height
        ])
        
        updateProgress()
        
        // instruction label
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Tap anywhere to cycle through the sample progress strings."
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    func updateProgress() {
        progressBar.progressText.text = sampleStrings[sampleIDX % sampleStrings.count]
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        sampleIDX += 1
        updateProgress()
    }
}
```

When you start, it will look like this:

[image]

Each tap cycles to the next sample string...

[image]